# Command to make all items on the list functions dependent on a given set of variables

Tags: list-manipulation, vector

The title basically. A typical example is the co-ordinates of a particle, and I want to introduce time dependence to define it's trajectory. For example, if I have
`cartco = {x,y,z}`,
I want to automate the defining of
`cartcofn[t] = {x[t],y[t],z[t]}`.
I can use `Table` command to make a loop over the list as I am doing for the moment, but is there an inbuilt function, like can `Thread` be somehow used?

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! here's one way: `c = {x, y, z}; cf[t_] = (#[t] &) /@ c` Does that get you what you're looking for?

Comment: yeah works. Thank you. Making the name of the name of function the dummy variable to replace, nice trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cartco = {x, y, z};
Through[cartco[t]]
```

> {x[t], y[t], z[t]}

Comment: thank you. This works nicely as well.